# How to draw multivariate normally distributed data that exhibit given correlation structure

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

I would like to draw features (covariates) from a multivariate normal distribution such that each feature has a standard deviation of 1 and a paarwise correlation between 0.3 and 0.7.

One can use the following code snippet to draw from a multivariate normal

```
        rng = np.random.default_rng()
        features = rng.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(n_vars), covar, size=n_obs)
```

However, this requires generating a (symmetric and positive semi-definite) covariance matrix with main-diagonal elements equal to 1 and off-diagonal elements between 0.3 and 0.7.

Comment: You can use a covariance matrix such as `covar = np.array([[1, 0.7, 0.5], [0.7, 1, 0.3], [0.5, 0.3, 1]])`.  Is the question how to create such a matrix randomly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Such a matrix is supposed to be randomly generated.